Editing App.js in React is not changing the default page for react when running npm -start
So I am trying to run some react code (simple search bar code) from my terminal. I put my source code within the App.jsx, the default made by "npx create-react-app", however, anytime I run npm start, I only get the default React page telling me to "edit App.js and reload". I ran my code within the sandbox environment within the react website and it was working fine. I am not entirely sure what I am doing wrong here. Any suggestions?

npm run start is the script to start the production app.
After you do the changes, type npm run build to create the build with that changes, than run npm run start.
For development you can use npm run dev and all the changes are automatically reloaded when saved.

Follow below steps:

Do the project installation
npm install

or
npm i


And run the project
npm run dev



